# Why Did Lester Frame His Nephew?

Tags: fargo-tv

Why did Lester frame his nephew in [*Fargo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2802850/)? As if it wasn't sociopathic enough to frame his brother.  I wonder why it was necessary to go to the extra trouble to go all the way upstairs and plant something incriminating in the kid's backpack.

Comment: Why the two downvotes?  Genuinely curious.

Comment: I dont know why this question was downvoted ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think he was actually framing his nephew as much as trying to give the police a reason to go to his brother's house. 
Lester probably counted on the blame falling solely on his brother once the police discovered the illegal firearm and the planted evidence.